# How to destroy fragment in kotlin?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments

I am trying to destroy the previous `fragment` when switching to another `fragment` on the same `activity` by using `getFragmentManager()?.beginTransaction()?.remove(MyFragment)?.commitAllowingStateLoss()` but on the `remove()` part, where I put my fragment's name, it says **Required: Fragment! Found: MyFragment.Companion** well I assume this is because I am using companion object in this `fragment` because I need it for the `putExtra` function. **How to destroy fragment even though there is a companion object in it?** Thanks.

Comment: in order to destroying the fragment, if you are using binding, you can just add this to your fragment
`override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }`

Answer (score 0):

[`remove()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentTransaction#remove(androidx.fragment.app.Fragment)) takes a *Fragment instance*, you're just passing it the name of the *Fragment class*.

```
class MyFragment : Fragment()

// Not this
remove(MyFragment)

// You have to get a reference to the Fragment object
// Either use the ID of a Fragment added in XML, or the ID of the container you
// added it to in a FragmentTransaction
val actualFragment =  fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.that_id)
// Or use a Tag you added in XML or through a transaction
val actualFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("some tag")

// now you have the Fragment, you can remove it
remove(actualFragment)
```

Because in Kotlin you can shorten `MyFragment.Companion.someProperty` to `MyFragment.someProperty`, just using `MyFragment` as a value (like you're doing here - `remove` expects an *object*) means you're actually referring to `MyFragment.Companion`. So the fact you have a companion object here isn't the problem, you're just doing the wrong thing with it by trying to pass it to `remove`.

Comment: @cactustuctacs hi thanks for the suggestion, but what is `remove(actualFragment)`? couldnt use `remove()` function. Also, how to find the ID of a fragment? Is it the fragment's name? Seems it is not.

Comment: @Tommy- the `id` is either the `id` of a Fragment you added to a layout in XML, or the `id` of a container in that layout that you added a Fragment to (with the `add` or `replace` functions in a transaction). You should read this: https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/fragmentmanager#perform (and maybe the next *Fragment transactions* section too)